# Please correct my price calculation per selected code

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to make the price change according to the selected topping.
It doesn't change on click.
However, it does not show any error either. Just not changing from the original price.
What should I do ?

```
double calculatePrice() {
  if (listTopping.isNotEmpty) {
    var _price = 0.0;
    // Get those toppings that are chosen (`isCheck` is true)
    final chosenTopping = listTopping.where((element) => element.isCheck);

    // Calculate the sum
    for (var item in chosenTopping) {
      if(item.isCheck) {
        _price = _price += item.price;
      }
    }
    return _price;
  }
  return 0.00;
}
```

This is the full code. I don't know what should I do.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:selfordering1/models/addon.dart';
import 'package:selfordering1/models/models.dart';

class Americano extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _AmericanoState createState() => _AmericanoState();
}

class _AmericanoState extends State<Americano> {
  List<Products> beverages = [];
  List<addonsize> listSize = [
    addonsize(
      id: 7,
      size: 'Tall',
      price: 0,
    ),
    addonsize(
      id: 8,
      size: 'Grande',
      price: 30,
    ),
    addonsize(
      id: 9,
      size: 'Venti',
      price: 50,
    ),
  ];
  List<addontopping> listTopping = [
    addontopping(
      id: 8,
      topping: 'Whipcream',
      price: 0,
      isCheck: true,
    ),
    addontopping(
      id: 9,
      topping: 'Javachip',
      price: 30,
      isCheck: false,
    ),
    addontopping(
      id: 10,
      topping: 'SoyMilk',
      price: 20,
      isCheck: false,
    ),
    addontopping(
      id: 11,
      topping: 'ExtraSyrup',
      price: 30,
      isCheck: false,
    ),
  ];
  var items = Products().beverages;

  bool _value = false;

  @override
  var _size;


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/lightwood.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100),
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(items[1].img),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  items[1].name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 30,
                      color: Colors.brown),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                  child: Text(
                    items[1].price.toStringAsFixed(0) + ' บาท',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        color: Colors.brown),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: listTopping.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                      return new Card(
                        child: new Container(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new CheckboxListTile(
                                activeColor: Colors.blue,
                                dense: true,
                                //font change
                                title: new Text(
                                  listTopping[i].price.toStringAsFixed(0) +
                                      ' บาท',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                value: listTopping[i].isCheck,
                                secondary: Container(
                                  height: 50,
                                  width: 300,
                                  child: Text(
                                    listTopping[i].topping,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 25,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onChanged: (bool? val) {
                                  itemChange(val!, i);
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: listSize.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                      return new Card(
                        child: new Container(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              RadioListTile(
                                  title: Text(listSize[i].size),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                      listSize[i].price.toStringAsFixed(0) +
                                          ' บาท',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 25,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black,
                                    ),),
                                  value: listSize[i].price,
                                  groupValue: _size,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _size = value;
                                    });
                                  }),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 200,
              child: Text(calculatePrice().toStringAsFixed(0) + ' บาท'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void itemChange(bool val, int i) {
    setState(() {
      listTopping[i].isCheck = val;
    });
  }
}

double calculatePrice() {
  if (listTopping.isNotEmpty) {
    var _price = 0.0;
    // Get those toppings that are chosen (`isCheck` is true)
    final chosenTopping = listTopping.where((element) => element.isCheck);

    // Calculate the sum
    for (var item in chosenTopping) {
      if(item.isCheck) {
        _price += item.price;
      }
    }
    return _price;
  }
  return 0.00;
}
```

As you can see I set the calculation at the bottom of my code.
I would actually prefer if you guys can help me add both size and topping price. I know some of my code is funny because I'm very new to coding.

Comment: `_price = _price += item.price`? Wut?

Comment: @Mat this is actually a correct code and it works as expected. You try it out on DartPad

Comment: @VelVetRose can you provide your error.

Comment: if its wrong, please do correct it. :'(

Comment: @VelVetRose you can just do `_price += item.price`

Comment: I don't care if it is correct or not, it is a ridiculous expression @quoci

Comment: it does not show any error, just the price does not change dynamically. It stuck as base price

Comment: I tried a minimal example of your problem and everything worked as expected. Can you check if `listTopping` is really not empty ?

Comment: How and where you're using the function? show us. @VelVetRose

Comment: I will provided the full code in Edit. Please help.

Comment: Done editing. Please have a look.

Comment: @Velvet I tried your code and it works fine. The reason why you get `price` is 0  is because you only have `Whipcream` as checked and the price of it is 0..

Comment: Ahh Thank you. That's actually enlighten. So, it's due to the setting not clicking. Do you mind if I continue asking about how do we make ischeck change via clicking? Or if you are busy, at least please give a keyword..

Comment: You need to call `setState` for updating the UI for your changes. Then it should work

Comment: Thank you. I'm very appreciated. I will search it up and try it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if(item.isCheck) {
        _price = _price += item.price;
      }
```

to

```
if(item.isCheck) {
    setState(() {
      _price = _price += item.price;
    });
      }
```

setState notifies the framework that the object has changed.

Comment: I tried. It doesn't allow to setState under if condition.
Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Make sure to use setState inside of a statefulWidget else it won't work